# Linkedin API invalid access token (Python)

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I just want to make a `hello world` post on LinkedIn.

One method is to use selenium, but i would rather use the API if possible.
Another method is to use the API which is well explained here:
https://www.jcchouinard.com/how-to-post-on-linkedin-api-with-python/

I execute the code, and get an access token from the website.

I then use the access token to get the user info.

From this i can make the post.

However, the issue that i have is that the access token can expire:

```
{
'serviceErrorCode': 65600,
'message': 'Invalid access token',
'status': 401
}
```

There is a way to get the new token manually here:
https://pypi.org/project/python3-linkedin/
with this instruction When you grant access to the application, *you will be redirected to the return url with the following query strings appended to your RETURN_URL:* `"http://localhost:8000/?code=#############################################&state=########################"`

My question is this: Is there a way to get a refreshed `access token` without having to do this manually ?

(In particular the LinkedIn site indicates that the token is valid for 2 months)

Comment: the token you're looking for it called a refreshToken, and can be exchanged for a access token. Is this the api documentation of linkedIn? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/programmatic-refresh-tokens   The refreshToken last longer than the access token, and you can just always be logged in this way in a secure manner, just refresh on a 401

Comment: okay.   was looking for something like this., so it could be the answer.  does the refresh token become the new access token (ie. does the user have to overwrite the old `access_token` with the `refresh_token`) ?

Comment: no, this is the flow. You use the app with your access_token, you save the refresh_token for later use. You get a 401 (access_token expired), then you preform the call described in Step 2 from the link. In that call you give your refreshToken away for a new access_token and a new refresh_token, and you save both. So the refresh token refreshes the access_token, it does not replace it, it is used to ask a new set of tokens from the api.

Comment: So you basically need a layer between your api calls that tries to automatically refresh on a 401, and then does the same request with the new access_token. If the refreshing fails, or your refresh_token expires, you have to authenticate / login again. That's how OAuth 2.0 works, you can always look up "access token, refresh token OAuth 2.0", the flow and idea is always the same

Comment: Much appreciated.